# Is there specific number input component in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

I've seen a component in Element UI for managing the amount of items, it's over here:

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input-number

I would want to use something like that in Vuetify, but I cannot find a similar component or even similar style example in Material Design. What's the best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**Update**: This answer pertains to version 1 of Vuetify, [yukashima huksay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57567420/9556193) is correct for newer versions of Vuetify.

Setting the `type` attribute to `type="number"` is the way to go.

**Original**:

You could just make your own:

```js
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  data () {
     return {
       foo: 0
     }
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      this.foo = parseInt(this.foo,10) + 1
    },
    decrement () {
      this.foo = parseInt(this.foo,10) - 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-container>
          <v-text-field v-model="foo" type="number" label="Number" append-outer-icon="add" @click:append-outer="increment" prepend-icon="remove" @click:prepend="decrement"></v-text-field>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>
```

Comment: `type="tel"` may be preferred: `type="number"` brings in some (likely unexpected) syntax limitations that `tel` doesn't seem to have. `numeric` doesn't seem to be available.

Answer (score 87):

Yes there is:

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="numberValue"
  hide-details
  single-line
  type="number"
/>
```

Check out [slider component in the doc](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/sliders#examples) for a working example.

Comment: Cool, if type="number" you even get up and down buttons at the right end

Comment: Well it works kind of ... as long as people keep in mind that you can still enter non numeric values manually.

Comment: @Hexodus `v-model.number` can help in that case

Comment: See the answer by UncertaintyP for some notes on the `.number` directive.

Answer (score 37):

In **vuetify.js v2.2.22** to convert your `<v-text-field>` in number you need write `v-model.number`

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model.number="foo"
  label="Number"
  append-outer-icon="add"
  prepend-icon="remove"
  @click:append-outer="increment"
  @click:prepend="decrement">
</v-text-field>
```

**type="number"** was delete

Comment: This is a little misleading.  See UncertaintyP's answer below.  `v-model.number` comes from Vue not Vuetify. 
 `type="number"` comes from HTML, not Vue or Vuetify.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number

Comment: Btw v-model.number is a nice catch, thank you!

Comment: Why I didn't know this before ?

Comment: In my case it is rendering  in the european number format  ( 0,02) , is there a way to tell it to use the US format (0.02)  ?

Answer (score 13):

Some concepts for number inputs get mixed up here.

1. I can not see **type="number"** being deleted in 2.2.22 https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/compare/v2.2.21...v2.2.22 Also I see it being rendered correctly at least in 2.3.10
2. The input field with attribute type="number" will be handled differently depending on the browser, OS and locale settings (e.g. I am still able to input free text in FF but not Chrome). Typically the keyboard layout changes on smart phones.
3. v-model.number is purely a directive for Vue. As you can see, internally, Vue simply tries to parse the input with parseFloat and uses that on success - otherwise it will be text and handled as a string in Vue/JS. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number

Answer (score -6):

Vue vuetify Code
using :rules="maxRules"

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field  v-model="text1" :rules="maxRules" label="Credit Amount"></v-text-field>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      limit:500,
      maxRules: [
        (v)=> {
          if (this.text1 > this.limit) {
            return 'Error'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```